# Website which contains video memes which are tagged

Tags: web-apps, web

Guys is there any website in which we can search for a word and a video containing that word can be obtained??
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yarn](https://getyarn.io/) is a website that uses machine learning to clip websites by dialogue.